# iPhone / iOS : AVAudioPlayer PlayAtTime: not working in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, avaudioplayer

Hi I have a number of AVAudioPlayers which I synchronize to start playing at the same time with with the PlayAtTime function. My code has been working fine for every iOS since 4 except that now it does not work in iOS 6. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Code:

```
//Mixers are AVAUdioPlayer instances loaded from before and are fine
NSTimeInterval shortStartDelay = 0.00;            // seconds
NSTimeInterval now = player.deviceCurrentTime

[miXer.music playAtTime:now + shortStartDelay];
[miXer.music2 playAtTime:now + shortStartDelay];
[miXer.music3 playAtTime:now + shortStartDelay];
[miXer.music4 playAtTime:now + shortStartDelay];
[miXer.music5 playAtTime:now + shortStartDelay];
```

NOTE: If I use the play function everything works (except that the mixers are out of sync of course) but the playAtTime fails to play the files.

Answer (score 4):

Your future time has to be greater than `deviceCurrentTime` for `-playAtTime:` to work. So says the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

You need to set `shortStartDelay` to something greater than 0.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you may need to call `prepareToPlay` first.

Comment: No. The reference reads "The value that you provide to the time parameter must be greater than or equal to the value of the audio player’s deviceCurrentTime property". And I tried directly entering times that are greater than deviceCurrentTime which is 0 when first run anyway.

Comment: Indeed, but in the example Apple provides they use a non-zero value of 0.01. Didja try that for your `shortStartDelay`?

Comment: @Zigglzworth: I think you need to post a little more code so we can see how you're setting up the `AVAudioPlayer`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have already solved this problem.

I was facing the same problem but simpler, as I only had one instance of AVAudioPlayer. When my application went to background it would pause playing the sound and on becoming active it should start playing the sound from the beginning.

What I did was set the *currentTime* property and call *play*:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *arg1) {
        [self pauseNarration];
    }];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *arg1) {
        [self playNarration];
    }];
}

- (void)playNarration {
    if ([self isAudioPlayerSet]) {
        [_audioPlayer setCurrentTime:0.0];
        [_audioPlayer play];
    }
}

- (void)pauseNarration {
    if ([self isAudioPlayerSet]) {
        [_audioPlayer pause];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one since the original AVAudioPlayer's playAtTime doesn't work with just the value offset you want to start playing.

// Custom function

```
func playAtTime(time: NSTimeInterval) {
    mediaPlayer.pause()
    mediaPlayer.currentTime = time
    mediaPlayer.play()
}
```

This flow is working well for me.